# Chat search doesn't work as expected

Tags: bug, search, chat

When I search with keyword: [**sorry can**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorry+can&user=&room=). I got the below results.

[image]

It has many results with text - **sorry can't.**

But when I tried to search with [**sorry can't**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorry+can%27t&user=&room=), It gives only two results. See the below image,

[image]

Something went wrong with the single quote.

**EDIT:**

As @IlmariKaronen said in the comment, *It seems that searching for [`sorry can&#39;t`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorry+can%26%2339%3Bt&user=&room=) instead works(!)*

Comment: SE search is notoriously bad at handling symbol search.

Comment: @rene: "SE search is notoriously bad" would have been enough.

Comment: They meant to make it better a fat month ago, that did not work out very well.  I now can't find some of my own posts back anymore like I used to.  Afaict it has something to do with not being able to figure out which punctuation character belongs to the query and which to the search term.   I know that angle brackets are trouble.  The old workaround is still good, use google.com and add, say, "site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: "Search doesn't work as expected" would have sufficed

Comment: @HansPassant: The problem with the workaround "Use Google" is that Google is a search engine for English, whereas SO content is written in "Programmerese". For example, Google considers "foo" a word, but ignores something like "&:", whereas in Programmerese, `&:` *is* a "word" (at least in the Japanese dialect aka Ruby), and "foo" is useless fluff. A "proper" SO search engine should take that into account.

Comment: totally unrelated: the specific mix of regulars from no less than 4 distinct chat rooms in this screenshot really makes me wonder where that was.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This might be of interest to you (apologies if you already know about it) or anyone else who wants to search for text with special characters: http://symbolhound.com/

Comment: it does work if you do `sorry can'` but as soon as you add a t behind it it breaks https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorry+can%27&user=&room=

Comment: @Tschallacka SQL.

Comment: yea, but the basic sql server escape routine doesn't work, `can''t` so I doubt it's an injection issue.

Comment: Lol Stack Overflow programmers have it so easy.  By the time they get notified of a bug, the entire StackOverflow has already debugged it and can almost tell them what line it's on :D

Comment: The problem is that users can't find the Chat Search. So we'll soon be releasing an entire new Chat Search identical to old one but with a different name only for Stack Overflow. Our engineers have been working full time for the past year on this.

Comment: It seems that searching for [**sorry can&#39;t**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorry+can%26%2339%3Bt&user=&room=) instead works(!). I blame misplaced HTML escaping.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good catch. Updated the question

Comment: Google is a troll. first two results brought me here: [https://www.google.com/search?q=metastackoverflow+chat+search+works+well](https://www.google.com/search?q=metastackoverflow+chat+search+works+well)